# Source file 'obj\ARM\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_<GUID>cs' could not be found

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

So, my Windows Metro app will not build because I get a number of errors that say `Source file 'obj\ARM\Release\TemporaryGeneratedFile_<GUID>.cs' could not be found.` The `<GUID>` is a variety of long alphanumeric strings.

This is accompanied by a number of other warnings that state `Source file 'obj\Release\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_<GUID>.cs' specified multiple times` The GUIDs do match up with the errors.

Here's another piece of info. If I run this app right right where I am developing, I have no issues. I still get the warnings, but none of the errors. The app runs without a problem. However, when I push this code to Git and then download the code, either to another computer or even the same computer, I get the errors above and the app will not run, which leads me to believe that some crucial file is not getting pushed.

However, I don't know where to look as I don't understand the meaning of the message. Does anyone have any insight as to what all these TemporaryGeneratedFiles are?

Comment: I accidentally deleted the obj directory and am now having this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the length of your path where the TemporaryGeneratedFile_[guid] are. In our case, these files were too deep in the folder hierarchy and the compiler couldn't find them. Moving the intermediary folder closer to the drive's root solved the issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain it, but I had a similar issue after I deleted the `obj/Debug` folder.  I ended up fixing it by unloading the csproj, and reloading.  Magically things just fixed itself.